# trouble accessing external float array

Tags: c++, scope, extern

I have the following program in two files

main.cpp

```
    float POW10[300];
    main(0
    {
        Fill_POW10();
    }
```

Fill.cpp

```
extern float *POW10;
Fill_POW10()
{
  for(int i=0;i<300;i++)
  {
    POW10[i]=i;
  }
}
```

This crashed with a segmentation fault. When I inspect, POW10 is NULL. However if I change Fill.cpp to

```
extern float POW10[];
Fill_POW10()
{
  for(int i=0;i<300;i++)
  {
    POW10[i]=i;
  }
}
```

the code works fine. I was thinking that POW10 is actually implemented as a pointer to floats and so the codes should be identical. Can you please explain why this is not so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First read this entry which explains your issue:

http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr1.html

Then read this follow up which explains the differences between array and pointer.

http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html

Comment: Thanks a lot .. I get the complete picture now.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays and pointers are completely different types. When you define a pointer variable, all you get is a single pointer that may or may not actually point anywhere. When you define an array, you get a contiguous sequence of objects.

You may be thinking of function argument types, where array types are transformed to pointer types. That is, `void foo(int arg[])` is equivalent to `void foo(int* arg)`. This is only true for function arguments.

Answer (score 1):

The type of POW10 is array of 300 `float`. It is **not** pointer to `float`. When you change your `extern` declaration to match the definition the problem goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Because the linker is not resolving your float * POW10 declaration to the float POW10[] definition, but actually creating a separate definition altogether, which ends up being uninitialized (NULL, as you experienced).

Comment: The linker sees just the name, so it **does** resolve the extern reference to the definition. And that's why the code crashes: the extern declaration has the wrong type, so the code that the compiler generates to access POW10 through the extern declaration doesn't access it correctly. Formally, the behavior here is undefined.