# Global Array of Structs

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault, global-variables

I'm like braindead and can't think right now so someone please help me out.

defined struct

```
typedef struct student {
char name[MAX_NAME_LEN];
int num_courses;
int course_id[MAX_COURSES_PER_STUDENT];
} STUDENT;
```

and made it global in 1 file `STUDENT student[MAX_STUDENTS];`
and tried to reference it in another `extern STUDENT *student;`,
but if i try to access `student[0].name` it contains `\0\0\0...` and I just get a seg fault.

Comment: How did you create the struct you tried to reference ?

Comment: `STUDENT student[MAX_STUDENTS];`. I checked and the data is fine in the first file, just not there in the second file. Probably has something to do with pointers and the fact that its an array, but I'm too tired to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the extern as an array as well, and not a pointer.

```
extern STUDENT student[];
```

See also: [trouble accessing external float array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323228/trouble-accessing-external-float-array/16323290#16323290)

Comment: So i just use [] instead of * and I'm good? That's the easiest fix ever.

Comment: Pointers and arrays are interchangeable in many places in C--but this isn't one of them. You're actually declaring an area of storage here, so you need to say that.